# IOS Auto Lay out dynamic leading and trailing constraints

Tags: xcode, autolayout

How can we set dynamic leading and trailing constraints like we give dynamic width and height through percentage of screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This
Add below Property in your viewController

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *cnstViewLeading;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *cnstViewTrailing;
```

Then set Outlet with your leading and Trailing like ......
[image]

---

and

[image]

**Use Like This**

```
//    replace value whatever you want with 0
    self.cnstViewLeading.constant = 0;
    self.cnstViewTrailing.constant = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make outlets of `NSLayoutContraint` and update its constants according to your need. After updating its constant you need to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`
Alternatively you can also use multipliers for percentage wise layouts.